# Is it possible to create a filter for the MediaWiki AbuseFilter extension that disallows .webp files to be uploaded to the wiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to create a filter for the MediaWiki AbuseFilter extension that disallows .webp files to be uploaded to the wiki?

I'm trying to set a filter that won't allow users to upload files that have a .webp extension.

edit: I only have access to Special:AbuseFilter -- I can't remove extensions installed on the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but it would be simpler to remove webp from the list of allowed file extensions ($wgFileExtensions).

Try this in the AbuseFilter:

```
(article_namespace == 0) &
(lcase(added_lines) rlike "webp")
```

Comment: @Rob_Kam, thanks. I would do that, but I only have access to Special:AbuseFilter.

Comment: This disallows edits to the main namespace which add the substring `webp` (including, for example, `This is a webpage`). OP said they want to disallow uploads. Also, `article_namespace` is deprecated, and `rlike` is not as performant as `in` when it comes to substring checks.

Answer (score 2):

If you had access to `$wgFileExtensions`, [@RobKam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76988137/1) would be the best solution. However, in the case you don't, you need the [`action`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter/Rules_format#Variables_always_available) and [`file_mime`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter/Rules_format#Variables_available_for_some_actions) variables:

```
action === 'upload' &
file_mime === 'image/webp'
```